# Why is there no php.ini file?

Tags: php, xampp, php-ini

Today working with php on windows, I experienced this error `Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()`. On reading  around I discovered that I had to edit the php.ini file. In the `C:\xampp\php` directory. I didn't quite find the file but instead php-ini-development and php-ini-production so I edited both. Still got the same error.

So I decided to check the actual php.ini file using `php -i` command and below is what I get. It seems there isn't one. Any solutions?

```bash
Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

Comment: Sounds like xampp. Just copy one of the two `php-ini-*` files to `php.ini` depending on your needs.

Comment: try to dump php_ini() directly from your code... maybe your terminal is not loading the same php.ini

Comment: @Michel I have actually found the php.ini file as file-type Configuration settings.

Comment: I am not familiar with what you are saying @skytorner

Comment: there's a php function called php_ini(), you can use it directly on your script. i thought maybe result would have been different than from the terminal to have some hints